# Retrieving answers from deleted questions

Tags: support, answers, closed-questions, deleted-questions

There were two questions posted by someone recently on measles virus, to which I devoted several hours of work in producing answers. The questions and answers disappeared completely over the weekend. They were not put on hold so I imagine the poster was removed from the list or something of the sort.

I would like to use these answers for other questions, but although I retain drafts  in text files, I do not have the final edited and illustrated versions. Is there any way I can retrieve them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user was removed, this is correct. Regarding your answer, you should be able to see your own answers, if not they are [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/84361/how-is-the-measles-virus-identified-and-characterized/84546#84546) and [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/84209/genome-sequences-of-measles-virus/84224#84224). If you still can't see them, let me know, then I will copy+paste them to a place like pastebin, where you can copy them.

Comment: No, I can't see it under my own answers, but was able to get it from the links you gave me. Thanks. I'll be more careful in future. The answer to the second question will probably fit (after editing) in the general question about virus purification.

Comment: @David Do you see them here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/22057 perhaps? There is a link to that page on the bottom of your own profile if you click "view more" under "answers."

Comment: @BryanKrause — Yes, and yes. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to find them yourself using either of the following methods:

- Anyone can find their deleted recent (i.e. posted in the past 60 days) answers by going to the [answer tab of their profile](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=answers) and clicking on "deleted recent answers". There is also a link for "deleted recent questions" on the [question tab](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions).
- As a 10k+ user, you can see a list of all your deleted posts by searching for [`deleted:1`](https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+deleted%3A1). (This method is both easier to use and more powerful.)

(I'll also note that anyone, regardless of rep, can see their own deleted posts if they have a link to them, even if it's [an answer to a deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179511/323179).)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Seems I have more ‘power’ than I thought. Too busy writing answers and annoying people to use (or abuse) it ;-)